# Layout XML file on Delphi

Tags: android, xml, delphi, layout

I have a doubt, I've done a lot of research and found nothing that solves my problem. I'm developing an Android app on Delphi XE7. But I want the layout to be like a card View. I've used the cardview in Java for Android. But I can't seem to find anything for Delphi. I have an Layout XML file for the cardview. Can I import or something like, this file onto my Delphi Project? If so, how can I do that?